# How to use dropdown value in text box as an decimal value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down menu where I  have some value I want to   get that drop down value in text box exactly .

I'm able to achieve this but where decimal value are available it's not coming properly

I'm getting value like this 0.25=025 and 0.50 =050

what should i do   to achieve my  output

like 0.25=0.25 and 0.50=0.50

```
Qty <select name="product_qty">
                   <option value="0.25">250gm</option>
                   <option value="0.50">500gm</option>
                    <option value="1">1kg</option>
                    <option value="2">2kg</option>
```

Comment: show your jquery please.

Comment: @nicael i did not use j query i used only  this code

Comment: so where do you get 025 instead of 0.25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Satyam without your code it is difficult to tell what are you doing wrong. Here is a jsfiddle and hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/efxgpsq0/

```
$(function () {
    $("select")
        .change(function () {
        var strText = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            strText += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        var strValue = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            strValue += $(this).val() + " ";
        });

        $("#textoutput").text(strText);
        $("#qty_selected").val(strText);

        $("#valueoutput").text(strValue);
        $("#qty_value_selected").val(strValue);

    })
    .change();
});
```